# Why can't the Ord trait provide default implementations for the required methods from the inherited traits using the cmp function?

Tags: rust, traits, ord

I have a newtype and I want to implement `Ord`:

```
use std::cmp::{Ord, Ordering};

struct MyType(isize);

impl Ord for MyType {
    fn cmp(&self, &other: Self) -> Ordering {
        let MyType(ref lhs) = *self;
        let MyType(ref rhs) = *other;
        lhs.cmp(rhs)
    }
}
```

When I try to compare two variables of my types, I get errors:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyType: std::cmp::PartialOrd` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl Ord for MyType {
  |      ^^^ can't compare `MyType` with `MyType`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialOrd` is not implemented for `MyType`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyType: std::cmp::Eq` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl Ord for MyType {
  |      ^^^ the trait `std::cmp::Eq` is not implemented for `MyType`
```

When I implement `PartialEq`, `Eq` and `PartialOrd` (`gt()`, `lt()`, `eq()`, `ge()`, `le()`, etc.), everything works fine, but if I provided `cmp`, we can infer functions like `lt()` and `eq()`! This is redundant! I don't like this!

When looking in [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html), I see this in the definition of `Ord`:

```
pub trait Ord: Eq + PartialOrd<Self>
```

This looks like the trait inherits from `Eq` and `PartialOrd`.

**Why can't the trait provide default implementations for the required methods from the inherited traits using the `cmp` function?**

I don't know how inheritance of traits works and searching turned up nothing useful, but I think this is something that should be possible.

How is this done in Rust? I hope not this way...

Answer (score 16):

For your specific case I'd use `#[derive]`:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct MyType(isize);

fn main() {
    let a = MyType(5);
    let b = MyType(6);

    println!("{:?}", a.cmp(&b))
}
```

If you need to special case your `Ord` implementation, you still have to write out that code, there's nothing that can save us there! You can still derive implementations for the other traits, if it makes sense to do so.

The other part of your question is ambiguous, so I'll answer it both ways I read it:

> Why can't `Ord` be automatically provided by anything with `PartialOrd`?

Let's look at the docs for [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) and [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html).

`PartialOrd` says: "The comparison must satisfy [*antisymmetry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation) and [*transitivity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation)", while `Ord` says: "types that form a [*total order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)". These are math terms and I won't do as good a job as Wikipedia will at describing them.

However, we can use floating point numbers as an example. Floats have a special value called `NaN`. Comparing against this value is tricky. For example, all of `1.0 < NaN`, `1.0 == NaN` and `1.0 > NaN` are false! These don't form a total order, but we can still compare one value against another. This is why `PartialOrd` exists - to allow us to compare types like this. incidentally, `PartialEq` exists for similar reasons.

We *can't* define `Ord` in terms of `PartialOrd` because we don't have the appropriate guarantees about the underlying types. This is Rust's type system saving us from making a mistake!

> Why can't `PartialOrd` be automatically provided by anything with `Ord`?

The problem here is that more types are `PartialOrd` than they are `Ord`. If we required everything to be `Ord`, then we couldn't have *any* floating point comparisons, because they don't have a total order, or we'd have to give up on having a total order and losing out on the safety that it provides.

However, there have been ideas to automatically do this for `derive`. Proposed [RFC 2385](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2385) would allow the above code to be reduced to:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Eq, Ord)]
struct MyType(isize);
```

> when I implement `PartialOrd` (`gt()`, `lt()`, `eq()`, `ge()`, `le()` ...)

Note that `PartialOrd` *does* have default implementations, you only need to implement `partial_cmp`. The others are there for ease-of-use or possibly performance reasons.

Comment: Regarding "`PartialOrd` for everything with `Ord`", OP doesn't seem to want to require `Ord` for types with `PartialOrd`, just having a *default* implementation for types implementing `Ord` to reduce redundancy. That is entirely reasonable and sound, it's just not possible in the trait system as of now (but probably doesn't bring enough benefit to be included in the future).

Comment: @delnan yet another way of parsing that paragraph! English is fun!

Comment: I think you don't answer very well the question "Why can't `PartialOrd` be automatically provided by anything with `Ord`?". The question asks for automatic `PartialOrd` **only** when `Ord` is already assumed, which isn't always, if it isn't always so where does "if we required everything to be `Ord`" comes from? It sounds rather confuse.

Comment: Is there any case where it's valid having `partial_cmp` _not implemented_ in terms of `cmp` when it's present? If not, then, having to write both manually with the same boilerplate seems like a limitation in the language.

Comment: @pepper_chico that would be the purpose of the RFC that is linked.

Comment: "We can't define Ord in terms of PartialOrd because we don't have the appropriate guarantees about the underlying types." `Ord` gives the guarantee and `PartialOrd` gives the implementation so you don't need a standalone implementation in `Ord`?

Comment: @TSK `PartialOrd` returns `Option<Ordering>`, indicating that there's some possible comparison that has no answer. `Ord` returns `Ordering`, indicating that every possible comparison has an answer. There's no universally-correct way of adapting the `Option` to the non-`Option`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Just unwrap the `Option`, because when you specify `Ord` you imply every `Option<Ordering>` is a `Some`.

Answer (score 10):

Please consider this as an addendum to the original answers, which are suited for your specific case. This answer deals with the second part of your question.

Consider this struct:

```
struct Person {
    id: u32,
    name: String,
    height: u32,
}
```

### **Equality: the `PartialEq` and `Eq` traits**

**PartialEq Trait**, From the docs

```
Trait for equality comparisons which are partial equivalence 
relations. This trait allows for partial equality, for types that do not
have a full equivalence relation. For example, in floating point numbers
NaN != NaN, so floating point types implement PartialEq but not Eq.

Formally, the equality must be (for all a, b and c):

symmetric: a == b implies b == a; and
transitive: a == b and b == c implies a == c.
```

So if you want to express what it means for values of your types to be equal, you must implement the `PartialEq` trait. Implementing it allows us to write `x == y` and `x != y` for our types.

```
impl PartialEq for Person {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Person) -> bool {
        self.height == other.height
    }
}
```

Note that we are deciding the equality of `Person` struct just on the basis of the heights. You could also have implemented this `eq` method if you want to compare every struct field:

```
fn eq(&self, other: &Person) -> bool {
     self.id == other.id && self.name == other.name && self.height == other.height
}
```

But it would be easier to simply add `#[derive(PartialEq)]` if that's the behavior you want.

**Eq Trait**, From the Docs

```
Trait for equality comparisons which are equivalence relations.

This means, that in addition to a == b and a != b being strict inverses, 
the equality must be (for all a, b and c):

reflexive: a == a;
symmetric: a == b implies b == a; and
transitive: a == b and b == c implies a == c.

This property cannot be checked by the compiler, and therefore Eq implies
PartialEq, and has no extra methods.

Derivable
This trait can be used with #[derive]. When derived, because Eq has no extra methods, 
it is only informing the compiler that this is an equivalence relation rather than a 
partial equivalence relation. Note that the derive strategy requires all 
fields are Eq, which isn't always desired.
```

PartialEq is for relations which are not necessarily reflexive (i.e. there can be such x that x != x) and that Eq is a marker trait which says that relation is also reflexive (and now it is a proper equivalence relation).

You can also implement the `Eq` trait manually with an empty impl block

```
impl Eq for Person {}
```

But, again, it’s easier to add `Eq` to your `#[derive(Eq)]` list.

### **Ordering: the `PartialOrd` and `Ord` traits**

The relative ordering of values is calculated using the operators `<`, `<=`, `>=` and `>`. To implement these for your own types, you must implement the `PartialOrd` trait.

Before you can implement `PartialOrd`, you must implement `PartialEq`.

```
impl PartialOrd for Person {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))    
    }
}
```

`Ordering` is an enum with these values:

```
pub enum Ordering {
    Less,
    Equal,
    Greater,
}
```

`partial_cmp` returns an `Option` and not an `Ordering` because there are types of which values cannot always be compared, such as floating-point numbers. `NaN`s are not representable numbers; expressions such as `3.0 < NaN` don’t make any sense. In those cases, `partial_cmp` returns `None`. Floating-point values are the only case in the standard library where this happens. More can be found [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/1083).

The fact that `partial_cmp` returns an `Option<Ordering>` has a consequence: it might not be possible to place two values, x and y, into a definite order. In practice, this means that implementing `PartialOrd` is not sufficient to make your values sortable. You also need to implement the `Ord` trait.

Before you can implement `Ord`, you must first implement `PartialOrd`, `Eq` and `PartialEq`.

For our `Person` struct, again we can delegate down to one of our member variables:

```
impl Ord for Person {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Person) -> Ordering {
        self.height.cmp(&other.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did `Person` get `cmp` function from in `PartialOrd` implementation? ( `Some(self.cmp(other))` )

Answer (score 8):

For starters, you can implement only `PartialOrd::partial_cmp`, as `lt`, `le`, `gt`, and `ge` have default implementations. Furthermore, if you implement `Ord`, you can simply implement `cmp` as usual and `partial_cmp` becomes just `Some(self.cmp(other))`.

However, if you only want to delegate to some field's notion of equality and ordering, then it's far better and easier to derive:

```
#[derive(PartialOrd, Ord, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct MyType(isize);
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't thought about defining `PartialOrd` in terms of `Ord`! I'd always just gone the other way and unwrapped the value.

Comment: That's close, but I also have to implement `PartialEq` when using PartialOrd. And for `Ord` also `Eq`. So: To implement `Ord`, implement `cmp`, then after that add the redundant implementations for `PartialEq`, `PartialOrd` and `Eq` which do nothing but delegate. That's sad, especially Rust is actually really elegant... Hope there still is a clean way to do it...

Comment: @Kapichu Well, `Eq` requires no methods, and `PartialEq` only one. Yeah, it's three bits of boilerplate, but honestly I never implemented any of those traits manually, `derive(..)` always worked for me so far. So it doesn't seem like a huge problem, especially since any fix would probably require some complicated do-what-I-mean magic in the compiler or standard library, or nontrivial extensions of the trait system.

Comment: Well, the source of the problem lies in Ord : PartialOrd + Eq . If I understand correctly, it means that when sth is Ord, it also is Eq and PartialOrd. In this case it should be possible that Ord provides methods of the inherited traits. Or the statement means that the traits behind the colon are required when sth is Ord. I couldnt find anything on Google about that.

Comment: @Kapichu Yes, it means anything that's `Ord` also implements those other traits. As I already said in a comment on Shepmaster's answer, `Ord` providing default implementations for `PartialEq`, `Eq`, and `PartialOrd` would be sound, but there is no way to express this in the trait system as of now. The trait system would have to be changed to support that, to ease what so far appears as a relatively minor inconvenience. Plus, it should be backwards-compatible, so if it turns out to be useful, it can be added at any time in the future.

Comment: My (probably naive) thought is that when you write the trait `Ord : PartialOrd, Eq`, you just write default implementations of `eq()` and `lt()` etc. in the body of that trait. This should be possible because `Ord` "contains" `PartialOrd`. But true there would have to be changes.

Comment: @Kapichu **because Ord "contains" PartialOrd** while true at the method level, they have different *semantic meanings*. This is what I'm referring to with my references to "total order" and all the other fancy math words.