# How can I implement the sum of squares of two largest numbers out of three for floating-point numbers?

Tags: rust

Exercise 1.3 of the book [*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html) asks the following:

> Define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers.

I've managed to answer this question, but only for integers:

```
use std::cmp;

fn sum_square_largest(x:isize, y:isize, z:isize) -> isize {
    x * x + y * y + z * z - min_three(x, y, z) * min_three(x, y, z)
}

fn min_three<T>(v1: T, v2: T, v3: T) -> T where T: Ord {
    cmp::min(v1, cmp::min(v2, v3))
}
```

But when I change the `sum_square_largest` function to:

```
fn sum_square_largest(x:f64, y:f64, z:f64) -> f64 {
    x * x + y * y + z * z - min_three(x, y, z) * min_three(x, y, z)
}
```

It gives the following `error: the trait 'core::cmp::Ord' is not implemented for the type 'f64' [E0277]`.

What is this? And how can I define this function to work with floating-point numbers?

Comment: It's probably min which is trying to compare f64s with each other, but the comparing function is missing for f64. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387711/implementing-ord-for-a-type-is-awkward for impl

Comment: This will go badly wrong if you have for example x = 1, y = 1, z = -1e100. Adding all three squares will give you catastrophic rounding errors if the smallest number is a huge negative number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floats do not implement `Ord` because they do not have a total ordering. `NaN` is false to compare against any value, including another `NaN`.

If you're on nightly Rust, you can use [partial_min](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/cmp/fn.partial_min.html), which makes these kinds of cases explicit.

You can also decide what to do in the case of things like `NaN`, and then implement a wrapper type over `f64`, and implement `Ord` for it, such that it handles that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid fatal rounding errors, you need to write your code as required: By adding the squares of two of the three numbers. Otherwise, if you have for example x = y = 1, and z = -1e100, then you get catastrophic rounding errors. The sum of the three squares gets rounded to 1e200, the same is subtracted, the result is 0 instead of 2.

It can be worse: If z = -1e200, then z*z overflows, three squares add up to +inf, you subtract +inf and get NaN.

```
let x1 = if x > y { x } else { y };
let mut x2 = if x > y { y } else { x };
if z > x2 { x2 = z; }

x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
```

If you consider NaNs the situation gets slightly more complicated. Obviously if you have two or three NaNs the result will be NaN. If you have one NaN, you need to decide whether (a) you don't care, (b) the result should be NaN or (c) the result should be the sum of the squares of the two numbers that are not NaN. In case (b) or (c), the result should only depend on the three values, and not on the order in which they are used.

The code above covers (a). If you want (b), then you need to make sure that z will be stored into x2 if it is NaN and x2 stays unchanged if it is NaN. You achieve this by changing the last line to

```
if z > x2 || z != z { x2 = z };
```

If you want (c) it is a bit more complicated.

```
let x1 = if x > y || y != y { x } else { y };
let mut x2 = if x > y || y != y { y } else { x };
if z > x2 || x2 != x2 { x2 = z; }
```

Comment: In general, it's more obvious to use [`is_nan`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.is_nan) to tell if a value is `NaN`. However, the OP's question is largely **caused** because of `NaN`! Because `NaN` causes `f64` to not hold a *total order*, that type doesn't implement `Ord`. This answer actually shows why it is entirely correct that the original code should **not** compile. The rounding issues are just icing on the cake.