# Why does `Ord` require implementing `cmp`?

Tags: rust

As `Ord` requires `PartialOrd`, which has an implementation of `partial_cmp`, `cmp` can simply unwrap its result and return it. Why do we need a standalone `cmp` method in `Ord`? In other words, why is `cmp` required but not provided by `Ord`?

The flagged duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387711/implementing-ord-for-a-type-is-awkward) is not a duplicate. This question is not about one trait being "automatically provided" by the other, but only the method inside the trait.

Comment: The comment you quote seems unrelated to your own question, since it effectively asks the exact opposite of yours.

Comment: @KonradRudolph True. Read it again and I think these two questions are not duplicates, because here I'm not asking one trait be "automatically provided" by the other, but only the method inside the trait.

Comment: It is likely that the answer is: performance. Building and then unwrapping `Option` potentially takes both space and time.

Comment: @freakish Isn't the entire point that creating and unwrapping an `Option` in Rust can be trivially optimised away completely in such a case?

Comment: @KonradRudolph what do you mean? It is unlikely that `Option` can always be optimized away. In particular when `partial_cmp` is complicated, it won't get inlined.

Comment: I would also say that it is good when you don't have an implicit `unwrap()`. If your `cmp()` can be implemented without `unwrap()`s, you can do it so and implement `partial_cmp()` in terms of `cmp()`, guaranteeing that you don't have panics. If it cannot, at least you can point to the exact points it can fail easily.

Comment: @freakish It should. How complicated can `partial_cmp` possibly be to prevent inlining for most types?! My experience with Rust is limited but I have vast experience writing libraries for C++, and `operator<` is almost always trivially inlineable code, even for complex types. In particular, note that, since the type implements `Ord`,  `partial_cmp` will *always* return `Some(...)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph come on, that's not for the compiler to decide how complicated a function can be. This solution gives a user a way to deal with such cases, if he wants to.

Comment: @freakish Of course it isn't, I didn't say it was.

Comment: @KonradRudolph in particular, if `partial_cmp` uses recursion (because you deal with a recursive structure like JSON) it probably won't be inlined. When you design something you should assume as little as possible.

Comment: @freakish Sure, and in that case the overhead of unwrapping the `Option` is either trivial, or the user can still opt to override the default implementation of `cmp`. This still isn't an argument against providing a default implementation that unwraps the result of `partial_cmp`. Also note that recursive calls often *can* be inlined by the compiler, even when they're not obviously tail recursive (modern compilers are pretty good at recognising such patterns).

Comment: @KonradRudolph the overhead is not necessarily trivial. Just because a function is recursive, it doesn't mean it is slow. For example, say most of the time the function returns a value without actually recursing - this means one branch followed by return most of the time. Then the overhead of `Option` scenario is: call function (potential cache miss) + build and return Option (potentially more expensive since Option takes more space than Ordering) + unwrap (at least one branch) vs one branch.

Comment: As for why it is not the default implementation: I suppose so that developers are more conscious about such decisions. Too much implicit stuff is not necessarily good.

Comment: @KonradRudolph btw, which compiler optimizes non-tail recursive functions, and in what cases, and how? I just wonder, cause I haven't seen such things. Although, nowadays I rarely work with low level languages like C/C++ or Rust.

Comment: @freakish *All* modern C++ compilers do this and, by extension, also Rust (e.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/n8EE6WKv3). Furthermore, compilers for languages such as Haskell and Ocaml reportedly also do. And, just to clarify, I didn't imply that recursion was slow (I know *very well* that this isn't the case). I am saying that for your specific example (comparing JSON documents) the overhead of unwrapping the result would be negligible.

Comment: @KonradRudolph your godbolt example is a tail recursion.

Comment: @freakish Nonsense. The last expression in a recursive tail call needs to be *the recursive call*. In my example the last expression in the `else` branch is multiplication.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ok, you're right. Still, this is a very simple example. Most of the time I used recursion in the real code was for graph traversal. This kind of functions often require more than one recursive calls inside, and I never seen them being optimized. Also, I'm not sure why you claim that the overhead of call + branch + create + return + unwrap (which includes another branch) is negligible compared to just branch. This can be a dominating factor if you deal with millions of JSON values, all of them being flat values (so actually not requiring recursive calls).

Comment: @freakish I would strongly question a design that is dealing with millions of small JSON values and is performance sensitive. Sure, in that case the `unwrap` will dominate the runtime but maybe the data structure was simply unsuitable to begin with (flatten first, compute after). And, again, in such a case the user is free to override `cmp`. I really don't see the issue. Providing a default doesn't preclude manual optimisation, and providing safe defaults is *extremely common* even when they potentially incur an overhead in C++, where the whole philosophy is one of zero overhead.